# Implementing graph search

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, graph

I am very new in Python, I would like to know if the style presented below attends a good implementation in Python.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import deque


def BFS(theGraph,source):
    n=len(theGraph)
    explored=np.empty(n,bool)
    for i in range(0,n):
        explored[i]=False
    explored[source]=True
    queue = deque([source])
    while len(queue)!=0:
        v=queue.popleft() 
        print "theNode: ", v 
        for i in theGraph[v]:
            if(not explored[i]):
                explored[i]=True
                queue.append(i)
    return explored    

def DFS(theGraph,source):
    n=len(theGraph)
    explored=np.empty(n,bool)
    for i in range(0,n):
        explored[i]=False
    explored[source]=True
    stack = [source]
    while len(stack)!=0:
        v=stack.pop() 
        print "theNode: ", v 
        for i in theGraph[v]:
            if(not explored[i]):
                explored[i]=True
                stack.append(i)
    return explored

def DFSrec(theGraph,explored,source):
    explored[source]=True
    print "theNode: ",source
    for i in theGraph[source]:
        if(not explored[i]):    
            DFSrec(theGraph,explored,i)
    return explored                

n=6 #number of nodes

theGraph=[set() for i in range(n)]

theGraph[0].add(1)
theGraph[0].add(2)
theGraph[1].add(0)
theGraph[1].add(3)
theGraph[2].add(0)
theGraph[2].add(4)
theGraph[3].add(1)
theGraph[3].add(5)
theGraph[4].add(2)
theGraph[4].add(5)
theGraph[5].add(3)
theGraph[5].add(4)
print theGraph

print "DFS: "
print DFS(theGraph,0)

explored=np.empty(n,bool)
for i in range(0,n):
    explored[i]=False


print "DFSrec: "
print DFSrec(theGraph,explored,0)

print "BFS: "    
print BFS(theGraph,0)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are some things that you could do to improve your code:

- First of all, your functions clearly lack documentation. Unless you know a little bit about graph theory, it is quite hard to guess that `BFS` and `DFS` stand for "Breadth-First Search" and "Depth-First Search". While the names may appear to be long, using the names `breadth_first_search` and `depth_first_search` would be really clearer.
- Also, docstrings to document what your functions do would be great. For example, you could write what `theGraph` is supposed to be since there is no obvious `Graph` structure to be used around. Documenting your functions, what are the parameters, what is the return type and what may be the preconditions and postconditions *really* matters :)
- Also, your code is too dense. You should add more spaces where it improves readability. My advice to follow the guidelines in the [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide. These guidelines are really good to write readable code.
- By the way, the PEP 8 says that you shouldn't check the `len` of a collections to know whether there are elements in or not. Therefore, you should change this line:

  ```
  while len(queue)!=0:
  ```

  ...to this one:

  ```
  while queue:
  ```
- These lines:

  ```
  explored=np.empty(n,bool)
  for i in range(0,n):
      explored[i]=False
  ```

  ...can be reduced to a one-liner thanks to [`numpy.zeros`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html):

  ```
  explored=np.zeros(n,bool)
  ```

  And since you don't use `n` except for constructing `excepted`, you may as well get rid of `n` and use [`numpy.zeros_like`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros_like.html#numpy.zeros_like) to construct `expected`:

  ```
  explored = np.zeros_like(theGraph, bool)
  ```
- While it is good for modules to have examples of how the module works, you generally do not want these examples to be run, unless when you explicitly run the module as a stand-alone. If you want your code to be a module, put the example part of the code in what we could call a "main block" (I don't know whether there is an official name):

  ```
  if __name__ == '__main__':

      n=6 #number of nodes

      theGraph=[set() for i in range(n)]

      theGraph[0].add(1)
      theGraph[0].add(2)

     # Rest of your example
     # code goes here...
  ```